# How can I make things visible one after another using transitions?

Tags: d3.js

I have a Website that creates a graph for imaginary stock portfolios.
It looks like this:
[image]

The idea is that the Graph grows over time (4 seconds or so) and every January theres a snapshot of the current porfolio, so you can monitor its growth.

I got the Lines to animate using this

```
var c=["red","green","blue","black"]
for(let x of pf){
    var path=svg.append("path")
        .datum(x) // 10. Binds data to the line 
        .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling 
        .attr("stroke",c.pop())
        .attr("d",line)

    var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
    path
        .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
        .transition()
        .duration(4000)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)


}
```

Now I would like to animate the points aswell, which are created like this:

```
var x=pf.flat(1);
// 12. Appends a circle for each datapoint 
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(x)
    .enter().append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
    .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return xScale(d.date.toDate()) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {return yScale(d.getValue()) })
    .attr("data-booked","true")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .on("mouseover", function(a, b, c) { 
        d3.select(this).attr('class', 'focus')
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.select(this).attr('class', 'dot')
    }).each(function(d,i){
        $(this).popover({ 
            html: true,
            title: d.owner.name+":"+d.date.format("MMMM YYYY"), 
            content: Tools.getMoneyTable(d),
            trigger:"hover"
        })
    })
$("#loading").remove()
```

JSFIDDLE: jsfiddle.net/6u82rsnk

Is there a way I can make the dots visible once a certain time thrwshold is made? So they become visible as the lines cross over them using a transition?

Comment: This can be easily done and it would be easier to demonstrate how, if you can make a JS fiddle/ Codepen/Blockbuilder so that I can show exactly what works. The partial code presented here makes it difficult to predict how the animation would happen. It would need to be timed with the line animation.

Comment: I would really appreciate that. Heres some fiddle

Comment: sorry wrong one https://jsfiddle.net/6u82rsnk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this there were several things I had to correct in your code.

1. I assigned the circles to a variable `dots` so that I can move the `.each` method on it separate.

```
    var dots = svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(x)
      .enter()
        .append("circle") // Uses the enter().append() method
      .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
      .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(d.date.toDate())
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var x = yScale(d.getValue())
        return x;
      })
      .attr("data-booked", "true")
      .attr("r", 6)
      .attr("opacity", "0")
      .on("mouseover", function(a, b, c) {
        d3.select(this).attr('class', 'focus')
      })
      .on("mouseout", function() {
        d3.select(this).attr('class', 'dot')
      });
```

Notice when the `dots` are appended, the attribute `opacity` is set to `0` thus they are added to the DOM but not visible.

2. The main trick to the animation is to add a `delay` ([d3.transition.delay](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_delay)) to the transition which utilizes the `xScale` and the `width` with the `duration time` in this case `4000` to calculate what is the delay in ms after which to apply the end of the transition.

```
      dots.transition()
      .duration(0)
      .delay((d, i) => (xScale(d.date.toDate()) / width) * 4000)
      .attr("opacity", "1");
```

3. The `each` method was added separately like so:

```
      dots.each(function(d, i) {
        $(this).popover({
          html: true,
          title: d.owner.name + ":" + d.date.format("MMMM YYYY"),
          content: Tools.getMoneyTable(d),
          trigger: "hover"
        })
      })
```

[Here is the full fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coolakul/pwLoe6n0/)